# Is it possible to force `round` to be in namespace std?

Tags: c++, gcc

I need to declare my own function `double round(double,double)` as `extern "C"` and it conflicts with `double round(double)` declared in `<bits/mathcalls.h>` (gcc 5.4.0). And that is just because I include `<cstdint>`.

There is the preprocessor variable _GLIBCPP_USE_NAMESPACES, which seems to enforce the namespace *std* around *round*, but defining it yields the error

```
/usr/include/c++/5/cwchar:141:11: error: ‘::btowc’ has not been declared
```

when `<map>` is included, which I need later on.

Is there any other way?

Comment: A common way to avoid conflicts in C functions is using a prefix, such as `double mylib_round(double, double)`. In general, you cannot prevent `double round(double)` from being in the global namespace. (Of course there might be a gcc specifc way, not saying the question is not valid.)

Comment: `_GLIBCPP_USE_NAMESPACES` looks completely broken. That's a shame.

Comment: @Quentin: So the answer would be "Theoretically yes, namely define `_GLIBCPP_USE_NAMESPACES`, but practially no, because `_GLIBCPP_USE_NAMESPACES` is broken"?

Comment: @MarkusParker I wouldn't know. I found your question interesting, so I followed your trail with `_GLIBCPP_USE_NAMESPACES`, but all I can find is bug reports of the whole library falling into pieces if you actually try to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks very much like there is no official way to prevent `round` to be in the global namespace and the existence of `_GLIBCPP_USE_NAMESPACES` in gcc's implementation of the standard library indicates such a possibility indeed, but I could not find any documentation about this preprocessor variable and even if it was possible in some older version it is currently broken.